# Water Coming in sliding glass door

Tags: leak, waterproofing, sliding-glass-door

It has been raining a lot and I noticed this evening the screen door track on our patio sliding door looked wet. I have noticed the water is leaching on to the floor also. The wall is dry and it is only in a certain area.

I have never noticed this before in the 15 months living here. What could be causing this and is there a repair or do I just have to ride it out?[image]

I spoke to the gutter guys and they indicated a problem so they could try and sell me a deck washing package. Still wondering why/how the water came in. I also looked out on the deck and didn't see a sealing issues. I will go look under the deck later.

Comment: Probably a clogged gutter somewhere nearby...

Comment: @Tyson had the gutters cleaned yesterday. On their slip left on the door, the cleaners said to call because there was something of note. Forgot to call today.

Comment: Call them and find out. They have an advantage, they know where the water is coming from.  We're just a bunch of guys/gals on the internet that have only seen the pic you showed, not the outside where the water is coming from.

Comment: What is tgevester?

Comment: Updated after talking to gutter cleaners.